I need a crash course in what's out there for mathematical modeling, simulations and visualizations
*Edit: Synchro for traffic signal timing
I got a bachelor's degree in math a few years ago, but the curriculum was almost entirely on paper so we weren't exposed to any software, languages, or other digital tools for working with numbers. I regularly find myself wanting to apply the concept to model, simulate, and visualize things like:

real world scenarios that depend on decision making (traffic, consumer habits)
financial modeling, risk analysis, investment projection
modeling with context-specific variable types (number, date, location, etc.)
physics calculations (force/load, fluid dynamics, energy)
pattern analysis/prediction/fit
live data that I can eventually hook up to automated/IOT
cool ways of visualizing/connecting complex concepts for teaching kids math

I'm looking to learn, and would love suggestions ranging from hobbyist to industry level. Free is best but if it's useful I would pay. Assume I know nothing, but can learn anything. I have experience working with 3D modeling software (Onshape, fusion, solidworks), but only to make 3D parts, have to run the numbers. I also have experience with Tableau and have worked on coding projects in C++, Python, Java, HTML, but never applied like this.
